# how to create a trigger to remove lat values that are almost duplicates

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table of lat, lng and deleteflag. Its MariaDB 5.3...

If someone inserts a value "close to existing items" I want it rejected or the deleteflag set.

I thought I could do it with a trigger??  Is this possible in mysql which seems has only limited trigger capabilities??

```html
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `lat` decimal(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` decimal(11,0) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON test FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE distance INT;
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO distance
    FROM test
    WHERE
    lat between new.lat-.1 and new.lat+.1
    ;

    IF distance > 0 THEN
        UPDATE test
        SET new.deleted=1;
    END IF; 
END
```

It works.
lat 39.2 39.5 39.8 40.0 40.2 40.4 40.6 40.8 41.0

But throws this error on closedups/dups.

#1442 - Can't update table 'test' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Q: How to silence that error??

Comment: Which one - rejected or delete flag? Define "close" is something approaching a mathematical sense. Why MyISAM? What mysql server version? What is your table definition `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`?

Comment: What makes you say MySQL has limited trigger capabilities?

Comment: You can build the logic into the INSERT itself

Comment: #strawberry  I want to use a trigger because I have INSERTS coming in from varried places. The trigger protects the data from any source.

Comment: @danblack .I show the distance calculation I use. The lat,lng are indexed so "between" works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it and the restriction is that triggers can't modify the table on which the trigger is has been applied (avoid many cases of cascading infinite recursion failures).

Instead of:

```
IF distance > 0 THEN
    UPDATE test
    SET new.deleted=1;
END IF;
```

Use:

```
IF distance > 0 THEN
    SET new.deleted=1;
END IF;
```

When the trigger completes the `NEW.x` values are used.

Ref; [syntax of triggers per manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/trigger-overview/)

Other notes;

- unclear why `deleted` is a decimal.
- MariaDB-5.3 - probably time you updated to a supported version. When you do, you can use Innodb instead of MyISAM.

If only a boolean is needed for deletion:

```
SELECT 1 
INTO distance
FROM test
WHERE
lat between new.lat-.1 and new.lat+.1
LIMIT 1
;
```